# FCM is generating the same token everytime in my activity

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

In my activity actually I have a button and on button click i want to generate `FCM` ... I want when app is restart and when button is clicked again `FCM` should generate different token everytime but it is generating same token everytime

```
FirebaseInstanceId
        .getInstance()
        .getInstanceId()
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(InstanceIdResult instanceIdResult) {
                String token = instanceIdResult.getToken();// here same token is generating everytime
                System.out.println("Tokensss " + token);
                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = SignupActivity.this.getSharedPreferences(cmn.SHARED_SPNAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor sharedPreferencesE = sharedPreferences.edit();
                sharedPreferencesE.putString(cmn.RegistrationTokenforFirebase, token);
                sharedPreferencesE.apply();
                tokenZ = new Token();
                SharedPreferences sharedPreferenceZ = SignupActivity.this.getSharedPreferences(cmn.SHARED_SPNAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
                String tokens = sharedPreferenceZ.getString(cmn.RegistrationTokenforFirebase, "1");
                DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("" + Number);
                //  DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference(""+Number);
                tokenZ.setToken(tokens);
                database.setValue(tokenZ);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Firebase tokens are generated on a per installation basis, meaning the only way to get a new token is to uninstall and reinstall your app.

Comment: there is not any possible way to update the token ?

Comment: see this SO answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58744495/fcm-is-generating-the-same-token-everytime-in-my-activity?noredirect=1#comment103778281_58744495

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing says that `getToken()` method will generate token every time you call it.

---

From [Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#sample-register):

> On initial startup of your app, the FCM SDK generates a registration token for the client app instance.

but also [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#sample-register) clearly say that there are multiple different scenarios in which the token "**may** change":

> - The app deletes Instance ID
> - The app is restored on a new device
> - The user uninstalls/reinstall the app
> - The user clears app data.

`getToken()` gives you the **current** token, **not** new token every single time.