# How to get different FCM registration token in a javascript application?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using FCM for pushing notifications and on my javascript side I have this code to get a new token when the user logs in:

```
    messaging.getToken().then((currentToken) => {
        //sending token to server to be associated with the loggedin user
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token. ', err);
    });
```

And when the user logs out I delete that token form my database, but if another user logged in using a different account on the same application(browser) and depending on [FCM is generating the same token every time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58744676/8618595) it returns the same token and now it will be associated with a different account.

So, my question is how to get a different token, or is there any workaround to handle the scenario of having the same application(browser) with multiple users can log in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Cloud Messaging has no concept of a user; all it knows is the token for a certain app on a certain device.

It's your application that makes that association from that token to a user. That also means that when you break the association in your app, you must force FCM to generate a new token.

The common way to do this is to delete the token when the user signs out by [calling `deleteToken`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.messaging.Messaging#deletetoken). After that, the next time you call `getToken()`, it will generate a new token.

Comment: Why is there "deprecated" label for deleteToken method?

Comment: The `deleteToken(string)` overload is deprecated, the `deleteToken()` is not.